# Display certain sequence only in VARCHAR

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column error_desc with values like:

Failure occurred in (Class::Method) xxxxCalcModule::endCustomer. Fan id 111232 is not Effective or not present in BL9_XXXXX for date 20160XXX.

What SQL query can I use to display only the number 111232 from that column? The number is placed at 66th position in VARCHAR column and ends 71st.

Comment: `substr(error_desc,66,6)` if the desired id always starts at the 66th position and is 6 characters long

Comment: [SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm)

Comment: this is the only string that you have?  or can the number be at a different location

Comment: @vkp thanks it works :)

Comment: @Hogan in current scenario, but whats ur advice to extract something like this at different position.

Comment: @TechSingh it depends on the platform, like I said, if there are no other numbers I would just cast to integer -- non-numeric digits are ignored in oracle

Comment: @Hogan - I don't know what you mean with your "cast" solution; SELECT CAST ('abc1002' AS NUMBER) FROM DUAL; (or the same with AS INTEGER) throws the error "invalid number" in Oracle. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @TechSingh - A number can be extracted even if it doesn't start exactly at position 66 and is exactly 6 characters long. But in that case, the question is, WHICH number do you want to extract? In your string you have three numbers, not one:  111232, 9, and 20160. Is it always the first number? Is it always a non-negative integer, or could it have a minus sign and/or a decimal point and a fractional part? All these can be searched for trivially, but the requirement must be crystal-clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT substr(ERROR_DESC,66,6) as ABC FROM bl1_cycle_errors where error_desc like '%FAN%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses regular expressions.

The challenge I faced was on pulling out alphanumerics. We have to retain only numbers and filter out string,alphanumerics or punctuations in this case, to detect the standalone number.

Pure strings and words not containing numbers can be easily filtered out using

```
[^[:digit:]]
```

Possible combinations of alphanumerics are :
1.Begins with a character, contains numbers, may end with characters or punctuations :

`[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[[:punct:]]*[a-zA-Z]*[[:punct:]]*`

2.Begins with numbers and then contains alphabets,may contain punctuations :

```
[0-9]+[[:punct:]]*[a-zA-Z]+[[:punct:]]*
```

3. Begins with numbers then contains punctuations,may contain alphabets :

   --    [0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*[[:punct:]]+[a-zA-Z]*    --Not able to highlight as code, refer solution's last regex combination

Combining these regular expressions using | operator we get:

```
select trim(REGEXP_REPLACE(error_desc,'[^[:digit:]]|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[[:punct:]]*[a-zA-Z]*[[:punct:]]*|[0-9]+[[:punct:]]*[a-zA-Z]+[[:punct:]]*|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*[[:punct:]]+[a-zA-Z]*',' '))
from error_table;
```

Will work in most cases.

Comment: What about `():.` and others. I think you want "not numeric" in your regex.

Comment: Yes, I got that. Figuring out.

Comment: @Hogan, I hope we have now covered required scenarios.

Comment: I think what would work here is `[^[:digit: ]]` (not digit or space) -- this should return all numbers separated spaces.  Then it is easy to parse.

Comment: @Hogan, with error_table as(
select 'Fan id 111232 is not Effective or not present in BL9_XXXXX for date 20160XXX.' error_desc from dual)
select REGEXP_REPLACE(error_desc,'[^[:digit: ]]',' ') from error_table;
does not work. Returns the whole string. If we have a better solution, please post, preferably answer..it would be a good learning.

Comment: @I_am_Bathman -- sure you have to include the rest of the regex. (hint, it is a `*`)